# How to add rows so that each group has equal number of rows?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with unequal numbers of rows per group, see `df` in the example below. I would like to add rows containing the group name and NAs in all other columns so that there is an equal number of rows per group like in `df.desired`. The rows should be added after the last row from the respective group.

Example:

```
df = data.frame(group = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"),  
                         col1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                         col2 = c(12, 13, 14, 15, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32))
> df
  group col1 col2
1     A    1   12
2     A    1   13
3     A    1   14
4     A    1   15
5     B    2   21
6     B    2   22
7     B    2   23
8     C    3   31
9     C    3   32
df.desired = data.frame(group = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"),  
                         col1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, NA, 3, 3, NA, NA),
                         col2 = c(12, 13, 14, 15, 21, 22, 23, NA, 31, 32, NA, NA))
> df.desired
   group col1 col2
1      A    1   12
2      A    1   13
3      A    1   14
4      A    1   15
5      B    2   21
6      B    2   22
7      B    2   23
8      B   NA   NA
9      C    3   31
10     C    3   32
11     C   NA   NA
12     C   NA   NA
```

I know how to do this with a loop but that would be super slow and I would prefer to use `dplyr` if possible. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(group = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"),  
               col1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
               col2 = c(12, 13, 14, 15, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32))
maxgp <- max(table(df$group))

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~c(.x, rep(NA, maxgp-n()))))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'group'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 12 × 3
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>    group  col1  col2
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 A         1    12
#>  2 A         1    13
#>  3 A         1    14
#>  4 A         1    15
#>  5 B         2    21
#>  6 B         2    22
#>  7 B         2    23
#>  8 B        NA    NA
#>  9 C         3    31
#> 10 C         3    32
#> 11 C        NA    NA
#> 12 C        NA    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can create row numbers for each group and then `tidyr::complete`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  tidyr::complete(group, id) %>%
  select(-id)

# # A tibble: 12 × 3
#    group  col1  col2
#    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 A         1    12
#  2 A         1    13
#  3 A         1    14
#  4 A         1    15
#  5 B         2    21
#  6 B         2    22
#  7 B         2    23
#  8 B        NA    NA
#  9 C         3    31
# 10 C         3    32
# 11 C        NA    NA
# 12 C        NA    NA
```

---

**Update** (from @Maël's answer)

After `dplyr 1.1.0`, [Per-operation grouping with .by/by](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_by.html) is supported for `mutate()`, `summarise()`, `filter()`, and the `slice()` family. The code can be simplified to

```r
df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number(), .by = group) %>%
  tidyr::complete(group, id) %>%
  select(-id)
```

Comment: Instead of `1:n()` it is recommended to use `row_number()`.